# Why does ARRAY destructuring assignment error pre-declared variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, destructuring

Here's an interesting problem I faced when trying a "shortcut" through date manipulation and end up in the dark forest of undefined type errors.

I'll let the code do the talking.

```
// The set up
let date = new Date()
let isoDate = date.toISOString()
```

Eg 1: This fails with `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`

```
let dArray, tArray, YYYY, MM, DD, hh, mm, ss
[dArray, tArray] = isoDate.split('T') 
[YYYY, MM, DD] = dArray.split('-') // << ERROR
[hh, mm, ss] = tArray.split(':')
```

Eg 2: This fails with `Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)isoDate.split(...) is not a function`

```
let dArray, tArray, YYYY, MM, DD, hh, mm, ss
([dArray, tArray] = isoDate.split('T')) // << ERROR
([YYYY, MM, DD] = dArray.split('-'))
([hh, mm, ss] = tArray.split(':'))
```

Eg 3: This fails with `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'undefined' of undefined` AND *prints the correct value of `dArray`*.

```
let dArray, tArray, YYYY, MM, DD, hh, mm, ss
console.log(dArray) // << ERROR 
[dArray, tArray] = isoDate.split('T')
[YYYY, MM, DD] = dArray.split('-')
[hh, mm, ss] = tArray.split(':')
```

Eg 4: And this works fine.

```
let [dArray, tArray] = isoDate.split('T')
let [YYYY, MM, DD] = dArray.split('-')
let [hh, mm, ss] = tArray.split(':')
```

SO... can anyone explain why? [The MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) show array destructuring assignments pre-declared before the assignment. There's even [a fun little quiz](https://www.nextptr.com/question/a56118674/splitting-return-values-using-destructuring) on the topic. Furthermore, when I type out the commands in the Chrome developer console, there are no errors in Eg 1, 3 and 4. But running inside client application code the browser, all fail except Eg 4.

This little snippet is part of a bigger utils package for quickly switching between ISODate strings and ms since epoch for custom date fields in a fintech order system.

It's a very curious error. I'll wager there's an explanation, and I'd like to know more about it from someone.

Comment: **Always** use semicolons, don't rely on Automatic Semicolon Insertion unless you're an expert and know how to avoid its pitfalls, or unless you use a linter, otherwise you will occasionally run into bugs like these

Comment: Oh, so the issue is the declaration with all the variables bleeds into the next line starting with dArray... never thunk it would be so. Seems I'm more of an expert now. :P

Comment: Eg `[dArray, tArray] = isoDate.split('T') 
[YYYY, MM, DD] = dArray.split('-')` since there's no semicolon following the `('T')`, the interpreter sees: `[dArray, tArray] = isoDate.split('T')[YYYY, MM, DD] = dArray.split('-')` as a single statement. It evaluates the right side first: `isoDate.split('T')[YYYY, MM, DD] = dArray.split('-')` which throws since `dArray` isn't defined.

Comment: Thats the explanation I was seeking... and I'm even more an expert thanks to you.